# wrapfigure do not works well

Tags: beamer, wrapfigure

I have this code using Beamer class, that does not work for me.
I need that the figure "intestino.jpg" is positioned right of the first itemization.

But what I obtain, is that the image is put on a new page.

```
    \begin{frame}{Ecosistema intestinale.}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item [ * ]L’intestino – inteso come unità funzionale intestino tenue / colon – è il più vasto ecosistema 
        del nostro organismo
        \item [ * ]È l’area di maggior contatto del 
    nostro corpo con l’ambiente esterno
        \item [ * ]Ha funzione di

    \begin{wrapfigure}[0.3\textwidth]{R}[]{300 pt} 
        \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{intestino.jpg} 
    \end{wrapfigure}

            \begin{itemize}
                \item assimilazione
                \item detossificazione
                \item immunologica – MALT/GALT –  
                \item endocrina.
            \end{itemize}
        \end{itemize} 

\end{frame}
```

Comment: Could you add a fully compilable `MWE`.

Comment: Try changing the {R} to {r}.

Comment: I've already tried it (r and R) and it still does not works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To me, this problem could be solved more elegantly with the classic minipage environment. For example: (PS please next time post a MWE with your question)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}{Ecosistema intestinale.}

    \begin{itemize}
        \item [ * ]L’intestino – inteso come unità funzionale intestino tenue / colon – è il più vasto ecosistema 
        del nostro organismo
        \item [ * ]È l’area di maggior contatto del 
    nostro corpo con l’ambiente esterno
        \item [ * ]Ha funzione di

    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.6\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item assimilazione
            \item detossificazione
            \item immunologica – MALT/GALT –  
            \item endocrina.
        \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
        \begin{figure}[0.5\textwidth]
        \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{intestino.jpg} 
        \end{figure}
    \end{minipage}
    \end{itemize}            

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You're right. I have upvoted you for your work.

Comment: Yes, minipage, I always forgot to use it :-(

Answer (score 1):

Another approach could be to use beamer's column mechanism:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Ecosistema intestinale.}
  \begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
      \begin{column}{.65\linewidth}
        \setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{ * }
        \begin{itemize}
            \item L’intestino – inteso come unità funzionale intestino tenue / colon – è il più vasto ecosistema del nostro organismo
            \item È l’area di maggior contatto del nostro corpo con l’ambiente esterno
            \item Ha funzione di
        \end{itemize} 
      \end{column}
      \begin{column}{.3\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
      \end{column} 
  \end{columns}
    \smallskip
    \begin{itemize}
    \item[]
    \begin{itemize}
       \item assimilazione
       \item detossificazione
       \item immunologica – MALT/GALT –  
       \item endocrina.
    \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize} 
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]